# Use jQuery for own attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
    <tr><td test='222'>sss</td></tr>    
    <tr><td test='111'>sss</td></tr>
    <tr><td test='222'>sss</td></tr>
    <tr><td test='111'>sss</td></tr>
</table>

$("[test]='111'").css('background-color', 'red');
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/MPmyc/1/

How can i set css only for test == 111 ? Now this added css for all TD.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: You should really use `data-` attributes if you want to invent attributes. Like `data-test="foo"` http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote [your attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) incorrectly.  Instead of:

```
[test]='111'
```

Write:

```
[test='111']
```

Edited code:

```
$("[test='111']").css('background-color', 'red');
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/MPmyc/2/

Also, if you're not basing your selection off an element `id`, then I recommend limiting selectors to the narrowest sensible scope.  I.e. select `td` elements:

```
td[test='111']
```

If the table had a class or `id`, I'd also narrow the scope to be under that table.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("td[test='111']").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual method to test for an attribute goes like this:

```
$('td[test="111"]').css(...);
```

with the entire test inside the `[]`, not partially outside as in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

This will [work](http://jsfiddle.net/nTeYf/):

```
$("[test='111']").css('background-color', 'red');
```

The predicate box mus surround the entire condition.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$("[test]='111'")` to `$('[test="111"]')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[test="111"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

You need to enclose your attribute conditional test in between the brackets, not just the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td[test=111]").css('background-color', 'red');
```